# Extra closing script tag in ReactJS course file?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently taking a React for Beginners course and following along using the course files provided. In the first chapter, they teach us how to create a simple Hello World example and in this example(both in the sample files and in the video) there is an extra closing script tag in the file. Just wondering if this has something to do with React or if the instructor made a mistake:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <title>Hello World Example</title>
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <!-- React -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.1/dist/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.1/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.13.3/dist/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>


    <script type="text/jsx">



    </script>
  </body>


  </script> <!-- Extra closing tag -->

</html>
```

Comment: Given how poorly the rest of it is formatted, and the fact that this is blatantly malformed HTML, you can safely assume that there cannot be not any deeper meaning that you missed, and it is just a mistake. But hey! Maybe you'll get a bonus point for noticing it, or something.

Comment: That's a mistake.

Comment: Sadly, this is a course on StackSkills.com, figured it would have been properly vetted. I bought it yesterday and so far both of the intro courses seem very outdated(using deprecated libraries, etc.) might just ask for my money back haha. Thanks for the feedback!